Scatter plot in python with x/y-ticks on a haircross?
I want to create a scatter plot with a hair-cross (vertical and horizontal line) at the centre. The x-ticks and y-ticks also need to be shown on this hair-cross. How can I do that?
Sample Required Plot:

The scatter plot that I created looks like below though:

Sample Code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate random data points
np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
x = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, 100)

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')  # Set the figure background to white
ax.set_facecolor('white')         # Set the plot area background to white

# Scatter plot
ax.scatter(x, y, color='blue', label='Scatter Points')

# Set axis limits and labels
ax.set_xlim(-5.5, 5.5)  # Extend slightly to fit the circle
ax.set_ylim(-5.5, 5.5)
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis', color='black')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis', color='black')

# Add lines to split the plot into quadrants
ax.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=1)  # Horizontal line
ax.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=1)  # Vertical line

# Set tick colors
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black')

# Add legend
legend = ax.legend()
plt.setp(legend.get_texts(), color='black')  # Set legend text color to black

# Show the plot
plt.show()


Does this example help? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/spines/centered_spines_with_arrows.html

@RuthC : Yes, exactly what I needed. Thanks :)
